# Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, arrays, fatal-error

In one of my scripts, I try to do the following

```
$data[] = self::get($row['sr_id']); // <-- line 55
```

However, PHP does not allow me to do this, giving me this **error**

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /file.php on line 55

The `self::get` function return either a bool, or an object.

**Edit:** The get function creates a new object which again loads data from a mysql database.

Comment: Check what $row contains

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code / the get method?

Comment: Try to find out whether the error is about `$data[] =` or about `$row['sr_id']`.

Comment: @Eiko: $row['sr_id'] contains an integer

Comment: Do what Flilip Ekberg suggests and show the result.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Old PHP versions accepted `$var[]` in expressions, allowed reading out the `$var` content regardless of syntax. PHP 5.1 made that illegal. But sometimes the error is triggered outside of the intented context.
So my guess **(again: show more code)** is that the preceeding line contains an unfinished expression, to which the `$data[]` joins.

In case of object attribute you can wrap your $data var into `{ }`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem in your case. (Else there is something in line 54, that you didn't show.) The right hand side can't reasonably trigger the error. Even array accessing `[]` an integer or object wouldn't trigger that fatal error.

So if nothing helps, just use `array_push()`. Work around PHP.

Comment: Thanks, the `array_push()` function did the trick, now it works. :)

Comment: Might be it, or perhaps the array was undefined or of a different type, which can cause this fatal error. (See below).

Answer (score 34):

The solution in my case was this:

- Bad line:

`$this->$ExtraTag[] = $fullscript;`

- Good line:

`$this->{$ExtraTag}[] = $fullscript;`

or

`$this->ExtraTag[] = $fullscript;`

Comment: Sweet. $this->{$ExtraTag}[] = $fullscript worked for me!

Comment: I'm not surprised the first "bad" line doesn't work and the last line does: the "bad" line is actually invalid syntax, and the last line is the intended syntax. The middle example is an ugly workaround to turn the first example into the third. I would recommend against that: it is less clear, less concise, and less performant (because PHP doesn't have a precompiler to optimise it away to the third example).

Comment: Great, but this doesn't solve the OP question.

Answer (score 2):

The error I got was:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in 
>       /pathtosite/drupal/sites/all/themes/zenui/templates/page.tpl.php on line 33

Sometime the problem is when you include a line like this:

```
$page['sidebar_first'][]
```

This might happen if you are copying a variable name and forgot to comment out the line.

There was two problems:

**1.** Missing semicolon

**2.** $variable[] must set a variable

After fixing these two problems my code read:

```
$page['sidebar_first'][] = $value;
```

Don't forget to comment out line you are not using to help with the debugging process

Hope this helps fellow programmers like me!

Answer (score 1):

I had same error with following:

```
echo implode(',', $array[]);
```

which should have been

```
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$data = Array();
$data[] = self::get($row['sr_id']); // <-- line 55
```

Comment: Not initializing arrays will not cause a Fatal Error.

Comment: it's alright, but if $data was previously an object or a var it may

Comment: then you know it's something on the other side: self::get($row['sr_id']); what does var_dump(self::get($row['sr_id'])); says?

Comment: Not initializing arrays can and _does_ cause a Fatal Error indeed, including in a simple expression such as {$arr['key']}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my script, the following line threw the same error:

```
$array[]=$value
```

I simply replaced it by

```
$array[count($array)-1]=$value
```

and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible problem could be an accidental double `==`.
For example accidentally doing `$myArray[] == $myNewValue;` would cause this error (because you are trying to read a value with the `==` instead of telling PHP to assign a new array index).