# how to add mobile number fetching of database insert into array

Tags: arrays

i have a table with 2 calumes,"id" and "mobile", i want get all mobile number of database and insert into a array like this $parameters['to'] = array("mobile_number1","mobile_number2","mobile_number3" ,...,"mobile_number last in database");
how to change this code for my request:

```
  DB_Connect(); // connect function
  $result = DB_Select("SELECT * FROM bs_Content");
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $i = $row['id'];
     $id[$i] = $row['mobile'];
  }
  for($i=1 ; $i<=$num_rows ; $i++){
     print_r($id[$i]);  
  }
  DB_Disconnect();

 // total i wand like array("9380009010","9380002020","930002021");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$numbers[];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $numbers[] = $row['mobile'];
  }
```

Comment: tanks for answer.i wand send sms with a api and i need to get mobile number of database and inset in array then put in variable like $parameters['to'] = array("9380009010","9380002020","930002021",...); and send how i can do?

Comment: vote me if this answer is useful for you. any way. 
try this for setting into `$parameters['to'] = $numbers;`

Comment: DB_Connect();
     $result = DB_Select("SELECT * FROM bs_Content");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $numbers[];
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $numbers[] = $row['mobile'];
 }
 $parameters['to'] = $numbers;  --------> Cannot use [] for reading in C:\wamp\www\myschools.ir\index.php on line 9

Comment: `DB_Connect();`  
`$parameters = [];`

`$result = DB_Select("SELECT * FROM bs_Content"); `
`$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); `
`$numbers[]; `
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ `
` $numbers[] = $row['mobile']; `
`}`
`$parameters['to'] = $numbers;`

Comment: this code dont work show error pleas you check this code

Comment: show me like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820258/cannot-use-for-reading error