# Illegal offset and cannot use [] for reading error

Tags: php

I am implementing an Ajax Cart in PHP5 at core level with this code:

```
$resp = $cart->getDetails(filter_var($_POST["pid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

if($resp == "" OR $resp == null)
{
    echo "Some Error!";
}

elseif($resp != "" || $resp != null)
{
    while($row = $resp->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $itemArray[] = array(
            $resp => array(
                'name' => $row["product_name"],
                'id' => $row["id"],
                'discount' => $row["discount"],
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => $row["price"]
            )
        );
    }

    print_r($itemArray);

    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
    {
        if(in_array($itemArray[], $_SESSION["cart_item"]))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
            {
                if($itemArray[] == $k)
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
}
```

I get the values properly in `$resp` since I checked it using `num_rows > 0` but there is an error, that cannot use [] for reading and that illegal offsets are used.

I am new to this thing and I have also tried modifying the code all over. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell in what line of code you get that error?

Comment: i am getting the illegal offset type error on line 29, i have just now solved the [] reading error

Comment: Which one is the line 29?

Comment: `in_array($itemArray[], $_SESSION["cart_item"])` is the buggy part, $itemArray[] can not used like that here. i can not see the logic there! in_array only needs one array and one string for testing.

Comment: error is being generated in this thing `while($row = $resp->fetch_assoc())
            {
             $itemArray[] = array(
                   $resp => array(
                       'name' => $row["product_name"],
                       'id' => $row["id"],
                       'discount' => $row["discount"],
                       'quantity' => 1,
                       'price' => $row["price"]
                        )
                  );
            }` the while loop thing

Comment: remove `[]` from `$itemsArray[]`

Comment: Take the [] out of line 29. It should just be `$itemArray, $_SESSION["cart_item"]`

Comment: the error are on this `if(in_array($itemArray[], $_SESSION["cart_item"]))` and `if($itemArray[] == $k)`

Comment: @aynber still array against array! very buggy code here.

Comment: @Nerea didn't work

Comment: can you please say me that where is error in my code so that it can be rectified.

Comment: Your code loses line by line any logic that was intend! But dont ask me, look at the comments, look at the code.

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav I show you the part of the code that are wrong, not a solution :)

Comment: @Akshay Shrivastav `in_array` does not wotk with keys! So you have to do it in another way. And this `if($itemArray[] == $k)` what does that?

Comment: if any item present in array matches the current value

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is when user adds a product to cart the ajax call will send they request to server with product id, then i will extract all the data related to that product id then the data that i receive i response i want to store it in an array like JSON array in PHP, then i want to check whether the S_SESSION['cart'] is emprty or not if its empty then push the values in array else make multiple arrays in an array with values of various products

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use \[\] for reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820258/cannot-use-for-reading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not understanding well what you want but I put this on answer becouse is too large to put on the comments :

```
 $resp = $cart->getDetails(filter_var($_POST["pid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

    if($resp == "" OR $resp == null)
    {
        echo "Some Error!";
    }

    elseif($resp != "" || $resp != null)
    {
        while($row = $resp->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $itemArray = array(
             array(
                'name' => $row["product_name"],
                'id' => $row["id"],
                'discount' => $row["discount"],
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => $row["price"]
            )
            );
        }

    print_r($itemArray);

    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
    {
        if(in_array($itemArray, $_SESSION["cart_item"]))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
            {
                if(in_array($k, $itemArray))
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
    }
```

Comment: That perfectly worked for me @Nerea that's what i wanted, thanks a lot :) i just had one more question to ask no i can see the result in Array { 0 ans so inside the elements if i have generated one more array then that will be array { 1 how to append that array with the previous one ?

Comment: To merge two arrays you can use `$final_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);`

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you meant, but you have an error in this line:

```
if(in_array($itemArray[], $_SESSION["cart_item"])) …
```

The first parameter, `$itemArray[]` is causing the problem.

The notation `$itemArray[]` is a special PHP short hand for pushing an element on to an array. You use it this way:

```
$itemArray[]='new value';
```

However, you can only use it on the left hand side of an assignment expression. As you see, it generates an error if you try to read from it, which has no meaning.

Comment: i am searching whether the product user is adding is already present in array or not if then then the product quantitiy will be increased by +1

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav It doesn’t make any difference. You can only use `$itemArray[]` in an assignment. It’s the equivalent of `array_push($itemArray,'new value')`. You cannot use it in a context where you’re supposed to be reading something, which I see you have done more than once.

Comment: can you please help in editing the code, i am trying to achieve this `what i am trying to achieve is when user adds a product to cart the ajax call will send they request to server with product id, then i will extract all the data related to that product id then the data that i receive i response i want to store it in an array like JSON array in PHP, then i want to check whether the S_SESSION['cart'] is emprty or not if its empty then push the values in array else make multiple arrays in an array with values of various products`

Comment: As I said, I’m not sure what you meant, but you could try removing the `[]` altogether. I don’t see that you have an existing array called `$itemArray`, so I don’t see that you’re really pushing onto it. I see 3 instances where you have used it. It might fix it if you remove all three.