# Looking for proper way to inject HTML table into PHP code

Tags: php, html

Let me start by saying that i'm sorry if this is a complete noob question.

while using phpStorm, I have an array of `$teams` and by invoking `foreach` loop I tried to put each of the array section into an HTML table

here is what I did so far

I am getting `cannot use [] for reading`, I can't find an answer how to do that properly, thx in advance.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>ID</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        include dirname(__FILE__) . "/stats.php";
        global $teams;

        foreach ($teams['data'] as $team) {
            echo "<tr>" ;
                echo   "<td> $team['name']</td>" ;
                echo   "<td> $team ['id']</td> " ;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: what's in stats.php ?

Comment: provide details of what $teams contain

Comment: In double quoted strings, you need to either remove the single quotes when fetching from an array `"<td> $team[name]</td>"` or wrap the complete expression in curly braces: `"<td> {$team['name']}</td>"`

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3820258/1531971 (among many others)

Comment: **Problem can no longer be reproduced**: see comment below: ["_Thanks, that did the trick._"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396094/looking-for-proper-way-to-inject-html-table-into-php-code#comment81745846_47396165)

Answer (score 3):

To get the string substitution working correct, you have to suround it with `{}` if it's something more complex than a simple var - especially array access.

```
 echo "<td> {$team['name']}</td>";
```

Comment: Removing the single quotes around the key works as well, but braces is, in my opinion, more readable (and less error prone).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.